# Python print radical sign in though getting type error about not being able to typecast bytes

Tags: python, python-unicode

Here is the error I'm receiving:

[image: img]

The code I am using in repl.it is the same one I wrote in Techsmart ((a browser based IDE for my class)( and worked perfectly:

```py
import math
square = []
perfect_squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225]
num = int(input(""))
for i in perfect_squares:
    if num % i == 0:
        square.append(i)
coefficient = max(square)
radicand = num // coefficient
coefficient = int(math.sqrt(coefficient))
if num in perfect_squares:
    print(int(math.sqrt(num)))
elif coefficient == 1:
    print(u"\u221A".encode('utf-8'), num, sep='')
else:
    print(coefficient, u"\u221A".encode('utf-8'), radicand, sep='')
```

Comment: Is it possible that Techsmart is using Python 2?

Comment: According to the Techsmart website the IDE uses version 3.4 so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might correct the encoding of the radical symbol in this line
`print(coefficient, u"\u221A".encode('utf-8'), radicand, sep='')` as follows.

```
import math
square = []
perfect_squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225]
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for i in perfect_squares:
    if num % i == 0:
        square.append(i)
coefficient = max(square)
radicand = num // coefficient
coefficient = int(math.sqrt(coefficient))
if num in perfect_squares:
    print(int(math.sqrt(num)))
else:
    print(coefficient, "\u221A", radicand, sep='')
```